# SQLi safe? Multiple .where request using OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Using Rails 5. Is this safe, or could this query be SQL injected?

(There's a form for selecting the region_ids on my site)

```
results = results.joins(:regionmemberships).where("regionmemberships.region_id = ? OR regionmemberships.region_id = ?", 0, 2)   if region_id.present?
```

I've read that `results.where('regionmemberships.region_id = ?', region_id)`

.. is safe. But is the first statement, when using OR also safe?

Or is there a more secure way to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it safe? Well it's safer than:

```
"regionmemberships.region_id = #{ params[:region_id] }
 OR regionmemberships.region_id = #{ params[:other_id] }"
```

As it uses a parameterized query which prevents SQL injection. However you don't need to construct the SQL from a string in the first place:

```
results.joins(:regionmemberships)
       .where(regionmemberships: { region_id: params[:region_id] })
```

You can also use a array with where:

```
results.joins(:regionmemberships)
           .where(regionmemberships: { region_id: [1,2,5] })
```

And it will generate:

```
WHERE regionmemberships.region_id IN (1,2,5)
```

Which is better than using `OR`.

Comment: What a great and detailed answer! Thanks! Is the last 3 examples MORE safe than my statement? Or would they ultimatively have the same effect? (Except they're nicer written)

Comment: From a security standpoint its the same - using `WHERE a IN (1,2,3)` is slightly more efficient than using `WHERE a = 1 OR a = 2 OR a = 3`.

Comment: Efficient in what way? In terms of security or in terms of being the shortest/best way to query?

Comment: @sneglefar Max meant more performant rather than more efficient which it definitely is

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(m.cid) AS count FROM councils AS c LEFT JOIN membership AS m ON c.id = m.cid GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.